# Epidemiological curve using R and epitools gives wrong epiweeks

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have been trying to make epidemic curves in `R` with the `epitools` package. According to the documentation, you can automatically generate epidemiological weeks from a date variable, similar as I have been doing for long in `STATA`. Fyi, epidemiological weeks are different from yearly week numbers:

> The first epi week of the year ends, by definition, on the first
>   Saturday of January, as long as it falls at least four days into the
>   month. Each epi week begins on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday.

- http://www.cmmcp.org/epiweek.htm
- https://wiki.ecdc.europa.eu/fem/f/1287/p/576/681.aspx#681

  graphlabels<-epicurve.weeks(DATE_variable, 
                              axisnames=FALSE, 
                              xlab = "Week of Year", 
                              ylab = "Cases per week",
                              tick.offset = 0.5, 
                              col=mypalette)
              axis(1, 
                   at = graphlabels$xvals, 
                   labels = graphlabels$cweek, 
                   tick = FALSE, 
                   line = 0,
  )

This automatically generated a nice curve:

[image: http://imgur.com/AG2P5mM]

"Hurray!!", I thought. But, alas, being a scientist I double checked the data using `STATA` as well as manually and noticed that the data does not correspond!

- Am I doing something wrong with `epitool` package that it gives me wrong epic weeks?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Most importantly, you should add some data using e.g. `dput(DATE_variable)`.

Comment: I also think that your implication that STATA's version is "scientifically correct" is subject to dispute. Relocating the weeks at the left side distorts the year information.

Comment: After studying the `?epicurve.weeks` page a bit, I see that your understanding of the "week" definition does not agree with the 'epitools' author's definition.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. There are different countries/organisations using different epidemiological week definitions. I guess my organisation's definition does not follow that of EPITOOLS.  [link(]https://wiki.ecdc.europa.eu/fem/f/1287/p/576/681.aspx#681).

Comment: If you had followed the advice of @shadow we might have fixed your problem, nonetheless.

Comment: @MJBOB, could you write up these differences as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker I have added the differences and BondedDust/shadow I will add sample data for the next time. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After some further discussion and research, there are differences in how epidemiological weeks can be calculated.

**EPITOOLS as.week**

> In public health, reportable diseases are often reported by 'disease
>   week' (either week of reporting or week of symptom onset). In R, weeks
>   are numbered from 0 to 53 in the same year. The first day of week 1
>   starts with either the first Sunday or Monday of the year. Days before
>   week 1 are numbered as 0s. In contrast to R, the as.week function
>   generates weeks numbered from 1 to 53. The week before week 1 takes on
>   the value (52 or 53) from the last week of the previous year. The
>   as.week functions facilitates working with multiple years and
>   generating epidemic curves.

**MMWR week**

> Values for MMWR week range from 1 to 53, although most years consist
>   of 52 weeks. The first day of any MMWR week is Sunday. MMWR week
>   numbering is sequential beginning with 1 and incrementing with each
>   week to a maximum of 52 or 53. MMWR week #1 of an MMWR year is the
>   first week of the year that has at least four days in the calendar
>   year. For example, if January 1 occurs on a Sunday, Monday, Tuesday or
>   Wednesday, the calendar week that includes January 1 would be MMWR
>   week #1. If January 1 occurs on a Thursday, Friday, or Saturday, the
>   calendar week that includes January 1 would be the last MMWR week of
>   the previous year (#52 or #53). Because of this rule, December 29, 30,
>   and 31 could potentially fall into MMWR week #1 of the following MMWR
>   year.

**EPIWEEK for STATA**

> Each epidemiological week begins on a Sunday and ends on Saturday. And
>   the first epidemiological week of year ends on the first Saturday of
>   January, provided that it falls at least four or more days into the
>   month

**ISO (or business) week**

> An ISO week-numbering year (also called ISO year informally) has 52 or
>   53 full weeks. That is 364 or 371 days instead of the usual 365 or 366
>   days. The extra week is referred to here as a leap week, although ISO
>   8601 does not use this term. Weeks start with Monday. The first week
>   of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year

**Week "u" in SAS**

> Each epidemiological week begins on a Sunday and ends on Saturday. And
>   the first epidemiological week of year contains Sunday. Weeks range
>   from 0 to 53 but do not always count 7 days

Comment: this is a useful information dump, but ... can you briefly comment on the specific aspects of the differences among definitions that lead to the differences in your results?  Are all of these definitions unique, or are there some pairs or groups that are practically equivalent?

Comment: The main character of epi weeks to be aware of is _If January 1 occurs on a Thursday, Friday, or Saturday, the calendar week that includes January 1 would be the last week of the previous year (#52 or #53)_.

Comment: In regards to calculating MMWR week in R, there is the *MMWRweek* package.